# nginx limit_req_log_level - where are the logs?

Tags: nginx, logging, ngx-http-limit-req-module

I've set up a `limit_req_log_level notice;` on my server and can't see the logs. I can see though that `limit_req` is working when I visit the pages. Alas, there is not a single log record nor in `/var/log/nginx/access.log` neither in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.

Where should I see the log records for the `ngx_http_limit_req_module` or at least to expect to see them?

I'd like to be also to able to see the contents of `limit_req_zone` table if that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase overall error logging level so messages from `ngx_http_limit_req_module`  module will also appear in the log:

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log info;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should see the logs in the `error.log`. For example

```
2023/07/17 17:17:12 [error] 3149683#3149683: *1157953 limiting connections by zone "addr", client: REDACTED, server: www.REDACTED.net, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1", host: "www.REDACTED.net", referrer: "https://www.REDACTED.net/"
```

It shouldn't be necessary to change the default log level because these are logged at the `error` level.

Not that this behaviour *could* be changed by setting [limit_req_log_level](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req_log_level), but the default is `error`.

> ```
> Syntax: limit_req_log_level info | notice | warn | error;
> Default: limit_req_log_level error;
> Context: http, server, location
>
> This directive appeared in version 0.8.18.
> ```
>
> Sets the desired logging level for cases when the server refuses to process requests due to rate exceeding, or delays request processing. Logging level for delays is one point less than for refusals; for example, if “limit_req_log_level notice” is specified, delays are logged with the info level.

Source: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req_log_level